# AutoFill macro, error occured when there is merged cell in the column

Tags: excel, autofill, vba

I have the following code: it works well enough, but when the column gets merged cell it turns out to be in error.  If there is any way to avoid count for the merged cell or be more specific - to count only data that contain only 7 characters in column B:

```
Sub Second()
Range("B15:I15").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B15:I" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub'
```

Comment: `but when the column got merged cell, it turns out to be error` Why not properly handle the error so that your code doesn't break? `to count only data that contain only 7 characters in column B` I am not sure I understand. What has this to do with Autofill? Can you explain with an example?

Comment: I have a original excel file with standard format, everyday I have to key in all the serial numbers (given by boss) that must contain only 7 character in column B (start from cell B15), from cell C15 to I15, there contain vlookup function that I manually key in to lookup for the detail of the serial number. I hope to copy all those formula for all the serial number in column.

I can do it by manual select all the cell with formula and then autofill it, but I am looking to create a macro to do it so that I can perform my task a little bit faster.

Comment: the merged cell will be at the bottom of my excel file, it is created by other and I am not suppose to delete it when i save the file and return it to my boss, I can delete and re-add it later, but it will consume a little time of me, and it does not fit the purpose of trying to save time.
Hope you can understand my poor english. Sorry for that I am a novice in excel macro

Comment: So C-I has formulas? And the merged cells can be anywhere in col B?

Comment: What do you mean by `the merged cell will be at the bottom of my excel file`? Bottom of Col B?

Comment: Alternatively can you post a sample workbook in www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: yes C-I has formula, I key in for row 15 only, so i hope to copy it or autofill it to all other serial number i key in start from B16 (with no gap in between) to the bottom of the data.

Comment: the merged cell will only appear at the bottom of the data, please give me some time to post a example workbook, I have to re-design it since the original file is confidential. many thanks

Comment: Sure no probs :) Just add "@" and then my name in the comment so that I get an alert when you reply

Comment: here is the link [link](http://www.wikisend.com/download/265258)

Comment: It doesn't have a merged cell anywhere?

Comment: there is only 2 merged in column B which are at the bottom, it the attached file, first sheet is without merged cell, sheet 2 contains merged cell

Comment: Oh in that case if the merged cell is always at the last row then it is easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the merged cell is always at the last row then it is easy. All you need to do is use the `.MergeArea.Count` to check if the last cell is merged.

[image]

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If .Range("B" & Lrow).MergeArea.Count > 1 Then
            Lrow = Lrow - 1
        End If

        .Range("C15:I15").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C15:I" & Lrow)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

And if you want to ignore the blank cell above the merged cell then, you can use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If .Range("B" & Lrow).MergeArea.Count > 1 Then
            If Len(Trim(.Range("B" & Lrow - 1))) = 0 Then
                Lrow = .Range("B" & Lrow).End(xlUp).Row
            Else
                Lrow = Lrow - 1
            End If
        End If

        .Range("C15:I15").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C15:I" & Lrow)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: there is 1 extra line at the bottom, is there any way to delete it?

Comment: it works, thanks a lot, I have another question posted with title (Copy the row that meet certain criteria to the bottom of my data), mind have a look please?